# LaTeX as ZIP for Windows

Tags: installing

Due to company/proxy issues I have not found a way to install LaTeX on my Windows computer.

Is there a way to get a pdflatex version that is self-contained?

Ideally, a zipped version of LaTeX to be just unpacked -- otherwise, an installer that does not need a network connection.

Comment: You can get the TeX live DVD: https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-dvd.html, https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html. But https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html also list a few other options.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot read DVDs ... I glanced over the other options which did not seem promising, but I will check them in more detail.

Comment: Well, you can download the `.iso` and mount that without even burning a DVD. You could also try to unpack the `.iso` and use its contents directly.

Comment: also you could consider sharelatex or one of the other online systems and not use a local install at all.

Comment: I made a tutorial about installing LaTeX. The steps can be applied to an offline installation (if you have access to an online computer at some point): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPnfHRE_W_g

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, but I need the command line pdflatex for using it with pandoc.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner due to the same company/proxy issues I cannot access youtube from the workplace ... but I will try at home.

Comment: Just get to any machine that has internet access do a full install of tl2018, then stick /usr/local/texlive2018 on a usb stick or whatever you can use and copy it to the work machine, you need nothing out of that directory after the install.

Comment: TL also has instructions for making a portable installation e.g. to USB stick ...

Comment: Do check that you are allowed to do this before you do it, won't you? Depending on your company's reasons for the restrictions, they may or may not be happy about your doing this. You need to check that first regardless of which method you consider using.

Comment: There is a portable version of MiKTex https://miktex.org/portable as well. But as far as I know you need a network connection for installation new packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your work computer runs Windows? If so, let me tell you how I use `TeXLive` on my work PC:

- If you need a program to extract files from the `TeXLive` ISO, get 7-Zip Portable (no installation required).
- Unpack the contents of the ISO to a folder on your PC (I used C:\soft\tl2017).
- Run C:\soft\tl2017\tl-tray-menu.exe (use the folder you extracted the ISO to). Click on the tray menu to launch a command prompt.

This will enable you to use a properly configured environment for running all command line tools included with TeXLive.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!